# Errors while Converting VB to C#

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

I have converted some `VB` code to `C#`.

Now the code is throwing errors on some line. Can someone help me in letting know how to fix these issues.

```
_with16.ConcaveColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromOle(Interaction.GetSetting(My.Application.Info.Title, "ProfileViewPlotOptions", "BackColor", System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Lime).ToString()));
_with22.Acceleration = Convert.ToDouble(Interaction.GetSetting(My.Application.Info.Title, "FTS1000", "Acceleration", Convert.ToString(200000)));
```

as far as I can understand , **"My"** keyword is not supported in  C#. Is there any alternative that can be used

Comment: Try `MyApplication.Info`.

Comment: doent seem to be working

Comment: What error are you actually receiving?

Comment: My doesnt exist in the current context..though I have added a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.dll and have added the namespace

Comment: Even if you've added the references `My` still won't work because it is specifically coded in VB.NET, and is just an alias for `MyApplication`. Maybe some of these posts can help: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d6ae4c08-98f5-4ae5-bf74-cffdb427be1e/c-equivalent-of-myapplication?forum=vsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`My` is a Visual Basic thing. If only those two lines are giving problems, you can replace that with:

```
var title = ((AssemblyTitleAttribute) System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyTitleAttribute), false)[0]).Title;

_with16.ConcaveColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromOle(Interaction.GetSetting(title, "ProfileViewPlotOptions", "BackColor", System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Lime).ToString()));
_with22.Acceleration = Convert.ToDouble(Interaction.GetSetting(title, "FTS1000", "Acceleration", Convert.ToString(200000)));
```

`My.Application.Info.Title` gives the value of the `Title` in the `AssemblyTitleAttribute` (MSDN links [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4fhza48(v=vs.90).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblytitleattribute(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: thats what I was looking for sir. Let me check and get back to you

Comment: getting error. System.Array doesnt consist a definition for "Title"

Comment: Sorry, see the edit. I'm on my phone and it's proving hard

Comment: sorry to bother u. after this i am getting 'System.Reflection.Assembly' does not contain a definition for 'GetCustomAttribute' and the best extension method overload 'System.Reflection.CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttribute(System.Reflection.ParameterInfo, System.Type, bool)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Ok, let me edit again. Sorry, that's what writing from memory gets you

Comment: this works.. wow ! nice. just wanted to know that would it serve the same purpose My.Application.Info.Title was serving ?.

Comment: It should. It's just a string with the assembly title